# View flicking on slow scroll of Android RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I have a horizontal linear layout at the top of  recycler view and I want to hide that view if `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` is > 2 and if findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition <= 2, that view should be visible.

I was able to achieve that with scroll listener on recycler view . But there is one problem, when you are scrolling slow view is flickering (showing and hiding fast). However this works fine if we do a fast scroll on recycler view.

This is my code

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

            val findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition =
                layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

            if (findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition > 2) {
                layout.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }

        }
    })
```

Comment: Is your `LinearLayout` part of the items inside the `RecyclerView` or is it just placed above it?

Comment: It is placed above it. It can not be part of RecyclerView due to certain logics around it.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering a bit, here's what I came up with. It's not the prettiest solution due to slight performance implications but it should do the trick.

Because your `LinearLayout` should change its visibility during scrolling and not just when scrolling is completed, we'll have to stick with `onScrolled`. While this method does provide the amount of scrolling done (`dx` and `dy`), it's provided in pixels (seemingly, I did some testing). This means that we'd have to convert this to dp to actually get some use out of this value which is probably too expensive to be doing every time the method is called.

Instead, I decided to just save the last couple of values of `findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition` in an array. This array is then checked each time `onScrolled` runs. It will look for items below your target value of 2. Your `LinearLayout` will only be shown if no values smaller than 2 are found.
This results in a more usable and more consistent `true` or `false` value that shouldn't cause flickering anymore.

Here's the code to achieve this behavior:

```
recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager // TODO: unchecked cast

        val prevValues = IntArray(5) // this can be changed to increase performance
        var counter = 0

        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy)

            prevValues[counter++] = layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

            if(counter == prevValues.size)
                counter = 0

            var smallerValueFound = false
            for(prevValue in prevValues.indices) {
                if(prevValue < 2) {
                    smallerValueFound = true
                    break
                }
            }

            if(smallerValueFound) layout.visibility = View.GONE
            else layout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
})
```

To decrease the amount of performance lost, you could only access the array every couple of times `onScrolled` is run, though this could have issues on its own. You could also decrease the array's size.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Tried it but still flickering effect is there.

Comment: Does hiding your layout cause your `RecyclerView` to change its size?

Comment: Yes. RecyclerView height get changed

Comment: Then the problem should be pretty obvious. When your `RecyclerView` changes its size, there's more space for items at the top. This will be filled with items above the second one. However, this causes your layout to be visible again, meaning the second item is at the top again. This will then cause the layout to be hidden again, starting a loop. You'd need some way to detect this.